# TortoiseSVN cannot create new repository on VisualSVN Server

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I have VisualSVN Server install on a Windows Server 2008 R2 Machine.  I have TortoiseSVN install on my local PC.  I can connect to VisualSVN fine.  I can checkout Projects fine.

My issue is when I want to import a New Project into VisualSVN Server from my local PC using TortiseSVN.

If I import a New Project using TortoiseSVN, I get the 3 errors.

- Unable to connect to repository at URL
- 'https://xxxxx.org/svn/NewProject'
- Access to '/svn/NewProject' forbidden

If I manually create an Empty Repository 'NewProject' on the Windows Server 2008 machine using VisualSVN Server, when I import the the actual Project from TortoiseSVN on my local machine, everything works.

I think I have all the Permissions setup correctly on the Windows Server 2008 machine.  Can the local TortoiseSVN machine create a New Repository on VisualSVN Server?  Do I need the Enterprise Edition to do that?

The work around is fine, but I don't want to create new Repository all the time on the Windows Server 2008 machine, if I can just do it all on my Local PC.

Comment: AFAIK you always need to create repositories on the server using `svnadmin`; if there's no repository, the svn server has no way to authenticate you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With any SVN server, you need to create the repo first.

With VisualSVN Server, create new repo in Visual SVN gui console, and setup the access permisions - all in gui console.

See https://www.visualsvn.com/server/screenshots/, images #5 and #6.

After repo is created and configured, you can checkout it with TortoiseSVN client

Comment: Thanks.  My last Job, they had it setup where people can Import Projects into the Server using TortoiseSVN.  I don't recall what SVN Server they were using, but it must have been a paid version (worked for a big company).  I'm trying to set one up for myself and a couple of people.  Thanks again for the answer.

Comment: Answer does help you?

Comment: Yes that does confirm what I was seeing.  Sounds like you have to create the Repo first on the Server side.  If that's the case, it'll be a little bit more work, but it's better than having nothing.  Thanks again for verifying that the Repo needs to be created first on the Server side.